# Oracle APEX, ORA-01752: cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table although my view has one PK

Tags: oracle-apex

I was trying to delete a row from the IG and the error 'ORA-01752: cannot delete from view without exactly one key-preserved table' occurs.

I have checked the columns for the IG and have make sure that it only has one primary key set.

The source for the IG is from a view where the only one table is used with a subquery in it.

I know I can split the delete process, however I want to use delete function from the IG

Please help!!

Comment: Het isue is not that you have a primary key set in your ig definition. The issue is that oracle cannot determine which row to delete based on that value.  Can you provide a reproducible example ?